# Image malformed downloading from FTP

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite, ftp-client

I have an app where I download a sqlite database from FTP.
The file works fine, if I upload into the tablet to the data folder works fine, but if I download with FtpClient as soon as I try to manipulate the database, Android creates a sqlite.corrupt.
I decug checking the file once is downloaded and it is already corrupt, but if THE SAME file I upload with Device File Explorer it works perfectly, where is the problem????

This is my code:

```
try{
 Thread myThread = new Thread(() -> {
                try {
                    FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();
                    ftpClient.connect(Constantes.FtpServer, Constantes.FtpPort);
                    ftpClient.login(Constantes.FtpUser, Constantes.FtpPassword);
                    ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
                    ftpClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);


                    try {
                        OutputStream outputStream1 = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File(ct.getDatabasePath("bdGeneral").getPath())));
                        boolean success = ftpClient.retrieveFile("BaseDatos/bdGeneral", outputStream1);
                        outputStream1.close();
                        

                        //Elimino registros
                        BbddGeneral bdGeneral = new BbddGeneral(ct, "bdGeneral", null, 1);
                        SQLiteDatabase d = bdGeneral.getWritableDatabase();
```

My database is named bdGeneral, once I create the SqliteDatabase Android creates bdGeneral.corrupt

Here you have what I get in console:

```
    (11) Invalid page count: nPage: 13477, nPageFile: 13375
    (11) Corrupt in lockBtree: rc 11, nPageHeader 13477, nPageFile 13375
    (11) printing out first page (size: 4096) of  DB /data/user/0/par.fg.fg2022/databases/bdGeneral
    (11) Page (1) content:
    (11)   1 - 53 51 4C 69 74 65 20 66 6F 72 6D 61 74 20 33 00 10 00 01 01 00 40 20 20 00 03 E1 FA 00 00 34 A5
    (11)   2 - 00 00 2B 1E 00 00 0F ED 00 00 00 0C 00 00 00 04 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00
    (11)   3 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 E1 FA
E/SQLiteLog: (11)   4 - 00 2E 30 3A 00 00 00 0A 01 9B 00 0F 72 0E 67 D3 0C 6B 0A 76 09 8F 08 3B 05 0E 03 E4 01 9B 00 00
    (11)   5 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
    (11)   6 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
    (11)   7 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
    (11)   8 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
    (11)   9 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
    (11)  10 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
    (11)  11 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
    (11)  12 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
    (11)  13 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 84 46 0B 07 17 1D 1D
    (11)  14 - 01 88 5F 74 61 62 6C 65 43 6C 69 65 6E 74 65 73 43 6C 69 65 6E 74 65 73 05 43 52 45 41 54 45 20
    (11)  15 - 54 41 42 4C 45 20 5B 43 6C 69 65 6E 74 65 73 5D 20 28 0A 5B 69 64 43 6C 69 65 6E 74 65 5D 20 6E
    (11)  16 - 76 61 72 63 68 61 72 28 32 35 35 29 2C 0A 5B 6E 6F 6D 62 72 65 5D 20 6E 76 61 72 63 68 61 72 28
    (11)  17 - 32 35 35 29 2C 0A 5B 74 65 6C 65 66 6F 6E 6F 5D 20 6E 76 61 72 63 68 61 72 28 32 35 35 29 2C 0A
    (11)  18 - 5B 64 69 72 65 63 63 69 6F 6E 5D 20 6E 76 61 72 63 68 61 72 28 32 35 35 29 2C 0A 5B 70 6F 62 6C
    (11)  19 - 61 63 69 6F 6E 5D 20 6E 76 61 72 63 68 61 72 28 32 35 35 29 2C 0A 5B 70 72 6F 76 69 6E 63 69 61
    (11)  20 - 5D 20 6E 76 61 72 63 68 61 72 28 32 35 35 29 2C 0A 5B 63 6F 72 72 65 6F 5D 20 6E 76 61 72 63 68
    (11)  21 - 61 72 28 32 35 35 29 2C 0A 5B 63 6F 6D 65 72 63 69 61 6C 5D 20 6E 76 61 72 63 68 61 72 28 32 35
    (11)  22 - 35 29 2C 0A 5B 6E 6F 6D 62 72 65 4D 6F 64 5D 20 6E 76 61 72 63 68 61 72 28 32 35 35 29 2C 0A 5B
    (11)  23 - 64 69 72 65 63 63 69 6F 6E 4D 6F 64 5D 20 6E 76 61 72 63 68 61 72 28 32 35 35 29 2C 0A 5B 70 6F
    (11)  24 - 62 6C 61 63 69 6F 6E 4D 6F 64 5D 20 6E 76 61 72 63 68 61 72 28 32 35 35 29 2C 0A 5B 70 72 6F 76
    (11)  25 - 69 6E 63 69 61 4D 6F 64 5D 20 6E 76 61 72 63 68 61 72 28 32 35 35 29 2C 0A 5B 6E 75 6D 44 69 72
    (11)  26 - 65 63 63 69 6F 6E 65 73 45 6E 76 69 6F 5D 20 6E 76 61 72 63 68 61 72 28 32 35 35 29 2C 0A 5B 65
    (11)  27 - 6E 76 69 6F 31 5D 20 6E 76 61 72 63 68 61 72 28 32 35 35 29 2C 0A 5B 65 6E 76 69 6F 32 5D 20 6E
    (11)  28 - 76 61 72 63 68 61 72 28 32 35 35 29 2C 0A 5B 65 6E 76 69 6F 33 5D 20 6E 76 61 72 63 68 61 72 28
    (11)  29 - 32 35 35 29 2C 0A 5B 65 6E 76 69 6F 34 5D 20 6E 76 61 72 63 68 61 72 28 32 35 35 29 2C 0A 5B 65
    (11)  30 - 6E 76 69 6F 35 5D 20 6E 76 61 72 63 68 61 72 28 32 35 35 29 2C 0A 5B 65 6E 76 69 6F 36 5D 20 6E
    (11)  31 - 76 61 72 63 68 61 72 28 32 35 35 29 0A 29 82 27 0A 07 17 25 25 02 84 0F 74 61 62 6C 65 41 63 75
    (11)  32 - 6D 75 6C 61 74 69 76 6F 73 41 63 75 6D 75 6C 61 74 69 76 6F 73 1B CA 43 52 45 41 54 45 20 54 41
    (11)  33 - 42 4C 45 20 5B 41 63 75 6D 75 6C 61 74 69 76 6F 73 5D 20 28 0A 5B 69 64 43 6C 69 65 6E 74 65 5D
    (11)  34 - 20 6E 76 61 72 63 68 61 72 28 32 35 35 29 2C 0A 5B 6E 6F 6D 62 72 65 5D 20 6E 76 61 72 63 68 61
    (11)  35 - 72 28 32 35 35 29 2C 0A 5B 70 6F 62 6C 61 63 69 6F 6E 5D 20 6E 76 61 72 63 68 61 72 28 32 35 35
    (11)  36 - 29 2C 0A 5B 70 72 6F 76 69 6E 63 69 61 5D 20 6E 76 61 72 63 68 61 72 28 32 35 35 29 2C 0A 5B 6E
    (11)  37 - 6F 6D 62 72 65 4D 6F 64 5D 20 6E 76 61 72 63 68 61 72 28 32 35 35 29 2C 0A 5B 70 6F 62 6C 61 63
    (11)  38 - 69 6F 6E 4D 6F 64 5D 20 6E 76 61 72 63 68 61 72 28 32 35 35 29 2C 0A 5B 79 61 41 63 75 6D 75 6C
    (11)  39 - 61 64 6F 5D 20 6E 76 61 72 63 68 61 72 28 32 35 35 29 2C 0A 5B 63 6F 6D 65 72 63 69 61 6C 5D 20
    (11)  40 - 6E 76 61 72 63 68 61 72 28 32 35 35 29 0A 29 86 2A 09 07 17 33 33 02 8B 79 74 61 62 6C 65 52 65
    (11)  41 - 66 65 72 65 6E 63 69 61 73 43 72 75 7A 61 64 61 73 52 65 66 65 72 65 6E 63 69 61 73 43 72 75 7A
    (11)  42 - 61 64 61 73 00 E3 43 52 45 41 54 45 20 54 41 42 4C 45 20 5B 52 65 66 65 72 65 6E 63 69 61 73 43
    (11)  43 - 72 75 7A 61 64 61 73 5D 20 28 0A 5B 42 72 61 6E 64 5D 20 6E 76 61 72 63 68 61 72 28 32 35 35 29
    (11)  44 - 2C 0A 5B 4D 6F 64 65 6C 5D 20 6E 76 61 72 63 68 61 72 28 32 35 35 29 2C 0A 5B 42 61 72 4C 65 6E
    (11)  45 - 67 74 68 43 6D 5D 20 6E 76 61 72 63 68 61 72 28 32 35 35 29 2C 0A 5B 42 61 72 4C 65 6E 67 74 68
    (11)  46 - 49 6E 63 68 65 73 5D 20 6E 76 61 72 63 68 61 72 28 32 35 35 29 2C 0A 5B 50 69 74 63 68 5D 20 6E
    (11)  47 - 76 61 72 63 68 61 72 28 32 35 35 29 2C 0A 5B 47 61 75 67 65 5D 20 6E 76 61 72 63 68 61 72 28 32
    (11)  48 - 35 35 29 2C 0A 5B 44 4C 43 6F 75 6E 74 5D 20 6E 76 61 72 63 68 61 72 28 32 35 35 29 2C 0A 5B 4D
    (11)  49 - 6F 74 6F 72 4D 6F 75 6E 74 5D 20 6E 76 61 72 63 68 61 72 28 32 35 35 29 2C 0A 5B 53 70 72 6F 63
    (11)  50 - 6B 65 74 54 68 65 65 74 5D 20 6E 76 61 72 63 68 61 72 28 32 35 35 29 2C 0A 5B 43 6F 6D 65 6E 74
    (11)  51 - 61 72 69 6F 5D 20 6E 76 61 72 63 68 61 72 28 32 35 35 29 2C 0A 5B 42 61 72 41 6C 74 30 31 5D 20
    (11)  52 - 6E 76 61 72 63 68 61 72 28 32 35 35 29 2C 0A 5B 42 61 72 41 6C 74 30 32 5D 20 6E 76 61 72 63 68
    (11)  53 - 61 72 28 32 35 35 29 2C 0A 5B 42 61 72 41 6C 74 30 33 5D 20 6E 76 61 72 63 68 61 72 28 32 35 35
    (11)  54 - 29 2C 0A 5B 42 61 72 41 6C 74 30 34 5D 20 6E 76 61 72 63 68 61 72 28 32 35 35 29 2C 0A 5B 42 61
    (11)  55 - 72 41 6C 74 30 35 5D 20 6E 76 61 72 63 68 61 72 28 32 35 35 29 2C 0A 5B 42 61 72 41 6C 74 30 36
    (11)  56 - 5D 20 6E 76 61 72 63 68 61 72 28 32 35 35 29 2C 0A 5B 42 61 72 41 6C 74 30 37 5D 20 6E 76 61 72
    (11)  57 - 63 68 61 72 28 32 35 35 29 2C 0A 5B 42 61 72 41 6C 74 30 38 5D 20 6E 76 61 72 63 68 61 72 28 32
    (11)  58 - 35 35 29 2C 0A 5B 42 61 72 41 6C 74 30 39 5D 20 6E 76 61 72 63 68 61 72 28 32 35 35 29 2C 0A 5B
    (11)  59 - 42 61 72 41 6C 74 31 30 5D 20 6E 76 61 72 63 68 61 72 28 32 35 35 29 2C 0A 5B 43 68 61 69 6E 41
    (11)  60 - 6C 74 30 31 5D 20 6E 76 61 72 63 68 61 72 28 32 35 35 29 2C 0A 5B 43 68 61 69 6E 41 6C 74 30 32
    (11)  61 - 5D 20 6E 76 61 72 63 68 61 72 28 32 35 35 29 2C 0A 5B 43 68 61 69 6E 41 6C 74 30 33 5D 20 6E 76
    (11)  62 - 61 72 63 68 61 72 28 32 35 35 29 2C 0A 5B 43 68 61 69 6E 41 6C 74 30 34 5D 20 6E 76 61 72 63 68
    (11)  63 - 61 72 28 32 35 35 29 2C 0A 5B 43 68 61 69 6E 41 6C 74 30 35 5D 20 6E 76 61 72 63 68 61 72 28 32
    (11)  64 - 35 35 29 2C 0A 5B 43 68 61 69 6E 41 6C 74 30 36 5D 20 6E 76 61 72 63 68 61 72 28 32 35 35 29 0A
    (11)  65 - 29 82 51 08 07 17 1F 1F 02 84 6F 74 61 62 6C 65 50 72 6F 64 75 63 74 6F 73 50 72 6F 64 75 63 74
    (11)  66 - 6F 73 00 E2 43 52 45 41 54 45 20 54 41 42 4C 45 20 5B 50 72 6F 64 75 63 74 6F 73 5D 20 28 0A 5B
    (11)  67 - 69 64 50 72 6F 64 75 63 74 6F 5D 20 6E 76 61 72 63 68 61 72 28 32 35 35 29 2C 0A 5B 64 65 73 63
    (11)  68 - 72 69 70 63 69 6F 6E 5D 20 6E 76 61 72 63 68 61 72 28 32 35 35 29 2C 0A 5B 66 61 6D 69 6C 69 61
    (11)  69 - 5D 20 6E 76 61 72 63 68 61 72 28 32 35 35 29 2C 0A 5B 70 76 70 5D 20 6E 76 61 72 63 68 61 72 28
    (11)  70 - 32 35 35 29 2C 0A 5B 73 74 6F 63 6B 5D 20 6E 76 61 72 63 68 61 72 28 32 35 35 29 2C 0A 5B 75 6E
    (11)  71 - 69 64 61 64 65 73 43 61 6A 61 5D 20 6E 76 61 72 63 68 61 72 28 32 35 35 29 2C 0A 5B 70 65 6E 64
    (11)  72 - 69 65 6E 74 65 73 5D 20 6E 76 61 72 63 68 61 72 28 32 35 35 29 2C 0A 5B 70 65 64 69 64 61 73 5D
    (11)  73 - 20 6E 76 61 72 63 68 61 72 28 32 35 35 29 2C 0A 5B 67 72 75 70 6F 44 74 6F 5D 20 6E 76 61 72 63
E/SQLiteLog: (11)  74 - 68 61 72 28 32 35 35 29 2C 0A 5B 64 65 73 63 72 69 70 63 69 6F 6E 4D 6F 64 5D 20 6E 76 61 72 63
    (11)  75 - 68 61 72 28 32 35 35 29 0A 29 81 64 07 07 17 2F 2F 02 82 75 74 61 62 6C 65 4D 61 74 65 72 69 61
    (11)  76 - 6C 50 65 6E 64 69 65 6E 74 65 4D 61 74 65 72 69 61 6C 50 65 6E 64 69 65 6E 74 65 00 E1 43 52 45
    (11)  77 - 41 54 45 20 54 41 42 4C 45 20 5B 4D 61 74 65 72 69 61 6C 50 65 6E 64 69 65 6E 74 65 5D 20 28 0A
    (11)  78 - 5B 69 64 43 6C 69 65 6E 74 65 5D 20 6E 76 61 72 63 68 61 72 28 32 35 35 29 2C 0A 5B 72 65 66 65
    (11)  79 - 72 65 6E 63 69 61 5D 20 6E 76 61 72 63 68 61 72 28 32 35 35 29 2C 0A 5B 64 65 73 63 72 69 70 63
    (11)  80 - 69 6F 6E 5D 20 6E 76 61 72 63 68 61 72 28 32 35 35 29 2C 0A 5B 63 61 6E 74 69 64 61 64 5D 20 6E
    (11)  81 - 76 61 72 63 68 61 72 28 32 35 35 29 2C 0A 5B 66 65 63 68 61 50 65 64 69 64 6F 5D 20 6E 76 61 72
    (11)  82 - 63 68 61 72 28 32 35 35 29 0A 29 83 72 06 07 17 1D 1D 02 87 35 74 61 62 6C 65 46 61 63 74 75 72
    (11)  83 - 61 73 46 61 63 74 75 72 61 73 00 E0 43 52 45 41 54 45 20 54 41 42 4C 45 20 5B 46 61 63 74 75 72
    (11)  84 - 61 73 5D 20 28 0A 5B 69 64 43 6C 69 65 6E 74 65 5D 20 6E 76 61 72 63 68 61 72 28 32 35 35 29 2C
    (11)  85 - 0A 5B 72 65 66 65 72 65 6E 63 69 61 5D 20 6E 76 61 72 63 68 61 72 28 32 35 35 29 2C 0A 5B 64 65
    (11)  86 - 73 63 72 69 70 63 69 6F 6E 5D 20 6E 76 61 72 63 68 61 72 28 32 35 35 29 2C 0A 5B 66 61 6D 69 6C
    (11)  87 - 69 61 5D 20 6E 76 61 72 63 68 61 72 28 32 35 35 29 2C 0A 5B 63 61 6E 74 69 64 61 64 5D 20 6E 76
    (11)  88 - 61 72 63 68 61 72 28 32 35 35 29 2C 0A 5B 69 6D 70 6F 72 74 65 5D 20 6E 76 61 72 63 68 61 72 28
    (11)  89 - 32 35 35 29 2C 0A 5B 69 6D 70 6F 72 74 65 44 74 6F 5D 20 6E 76 61 72 63 68 61 72 28 32 35 35 29
    (11)  90 - 2C 0A 5B 64 65 73 63 75 65 6E 74 6F 5D 20 6E 76 61 72 63 68 61 72 28 32 35 35 29 2C 0A 5B 66 65
    (11)  91 - 63 68 61 42 6F 6E 69 74 61 5D 20 6E 76 61 72 63 68 61 72 28 32 35 35 29 2C 0A 5B 66 65 63 68 61
    (11)  92 - 4C 6F 6E 67 5D 20 6E 76 61 72 63 68 61 72 28 32 35 35 29 2C 0A 5B 79 65 61 72 5D 20 6E 76 61 72
    (11)  93 - 63 68 61 72 28 32 35 35 29 2C 0A 5B 6D 65 73 5D 20 6E 76 61 72 63 68 61 72 28 32 35 35 29 2C 0A
    (11)  94 - 5B 64 69 61 5D 20 6E 76 61 72 63 68 61 72 28 32 35 35 29 2C 0A 5B 63 6F 6D 65 72 63 69 61 6C 5D
    (11)  95 - 20 6E 76 61 72 63 68 61 72 28 32 35 35 29 2C 0A 5B 63 61 6E 74 69 64 61 64 55 6E 69 64 61 64 5D
    (11)  96 - 20 6E 76 61 72 63 68 61 72 28 32 35 35 29 2C 0A 5B 66 65 63 68 61 52 65 67 69 73 74 72 6F 5D 20
    (11)  97 - 6E 76 61 72 63 68 61 72 28 32 35 35 29 0A 29 82 65 05 07 17 2D 2D 02 84 7B 74 61 62 6C 65 44 65
    (11)  98 - 73 63 75 65 6E 74 6F 73 4F 66 65 72 74 61 44 65 73 63 75 65 6E 74 6F 73 4F 66 65 72 74 61 00 DF
    (11)  99 - 43 52 45 41 54 45 20 54 41 42 4C 45 20 5B 44 65 73 63 75 65 6E 74 6F 73 4F 66 65 72 74 61 5D 20
    (11) 100 - 28 0A 5B 69 64 46 61 6D 69 6C 69 61 50 72 6F 64 75 63 74 6F 5D 20 6E 76 61 72 63 68 61 72 28 32
    (11) 101 - 35 35 29 2C 0A 5B 64 74 6F 30 31 5D 20 6E 76 61 72 63 68 61 72 28 32 35 35 29 2C 0A 5B 64 74 6F
    (11) 102 - 30 32 5D 20 6E 76 61 72 63 68 61 72 28 32 35 35 29 2C 0A 5B 64 74 6F 30 33 5D 20 6E 76 61 72 63
    (11) 103 - 68 61 72 28 32 35 35 29 2C 0A 5B 64 74 6F 30 34 5D 20 6E 76 61 72 63 68 61 72 28 32 35 35 29 2C
    (11) 104 - 0A 5B 64 74 6F 30 35 5D 20 6E 76 61 72 63 68 61 72 28 32 35 35 29 2C 0A 5B 64 74 6F 30 36 5D 20
    (11) 105 - 6E 76 61 72 63 68 61 72 28 32 35 35 29 2C 0A 5B 64 74 6F 30 37 5D 20 6E 76 61 72 63 68 61 72 28
    (11) 106 - 32 35 35 29 2C 0A 5B 64 74 6F 30 38 5D 20 6E 76 61 72 63 68 61 72 28 32 35 35 29 2C 0A 5B 64 74
    (11) 107 - 6F 30 39 5D 20 6E 76 61 72 63 68 61 72 28 32 35 35 29 2C 0A 5B 64 74 6F 31 30 5D 20 6E 76 61 72
    (11) 108 - 63 68 61 72 28 32 35 35 29 0A 29 81 11 04 07 17 31 31 02 81 4B 74 61 62 6C 65 44 65 73 63 75 65
    (11) 109 - 6E 74 6F 73 45 73 74 61 6E 64 61 72 44 65 73 63 75 65 6E 74 6F 73 45 73 74 61 6E 64 61 72 00 DE
    (11) 110 - 43 52 45 41 54 45 20 54 41 42 4C 45 20 5B 44 65 73 63 75 65 6E 74 6F 73 45 73 74 61 6E 64 61 72
    (11) 111 - 5D 20 28 0A 5B 69 64 46 61 6D 69 6C 69 61 50 72 6F 64 75 63 74 6F 5D 20 6E 76 61 72 63 68 61 72
    (11) 112 - 28 32 35 35 29 2C 0A 5B 64 74 6F 5D 20 6E 76 61 72 63 68 61 72 28 32 35 35 29 0A 29 82 08 03 07
    (11) 113 - 17 21 21 02 83 59 74 61 62 6C 65 44 65 73 63 75 65 6E 74 6F 73 44 65 73 63 75 65 6E 74 6F 73 00
    (11) 114 - DD 43 52 45 41 54 45 20 54 41 42 4C 45 20 5B 44 65 73 63 75 65 6E 74 6F 73 5D 20 28 0A 5B 69 64
    (11) 115 - 43 6C 69 65 6E 74 65 5D 20 6E 76 61 72 63 68 61 72 28 32 35 35 29 2C 0A 5B 69 64 46 61 6D 69 6C
    (11) 116 - 69 61 50 72 6F 64 75 63 74 6F 5D 20 6E 76 61 72 63 68 61 72 28 32 35 35 29 2C 0A 5B 64 65 73 63
    (11) 117 - 75 65 6E 74 6F 5D 20 6E 76 61 72 63 68 61 72 28 32 35 35 29 2C 0A 5B 63 61 6E 74 69 64 61 64 5D
    (11) 118 - 20 6E 76 61 72 63 68 61 72 28 32 35 35 29 2C 0A 5B 6E 6F 74 61 73 5D 20 6E 76 61 72 63 68 61 72
    (11) 119 - 28 32 35 35 29 2C 0A 5B 66 65 63 68 61 49 6E 69 63 69 6F 5D 20 6E 76 61 72 63 68 61 72 28 32 35
    (11) 120 - 35 29 2C 0A 5B 63 6F 6D 65 72 63 69 61 6C 5D 20 6E 76 61 72 63 68 61 72 28 32 35 35 29 0A 29 81
    (11) 121 - 0B 01 07 17 1D 1D 01 81 69 74 61 62 6C 65 41 6E 75 6E 63 69 6F 73 41 6E 75 6E 63 69 6F 73 02 43
    (11) 122 - 52 45 41 54 45 20 54 41 42 4C 45 20 5B 41 6E 75 6E 63 69 6F 73 5D 20 28 0A 5B 66 65 63 68 61 49
    (11) 123 - 6E 69 63 69 6F 5D 20 6E 76 61 72 63 68 61 72 28 32 35 35 29 2C 0A 5B 66 65 63 68 61 46 69 6E 5D
    (11) 124 - 20 6E 76 61 72 63 68 61 72 28 32 35 35 29 2C 0A 5B 61 6E 75 6E 63 69 6F 5D 20 6E 76 61 72 63 68
    (11) 125 - 61 72 28 32 35 35 29 0A 29 05 00 00 00 02 0F F5 00 00 00 01 47 0F FB 0F F5 0E E5 0E AA 0E 78 0E
    (11) 126 - 3C 0E 0E D4 A7 7A 4D 1D 0C EE 0C BF 0C 8D 0C 60 0C 2B 0B FA 0B C4 0B 96 0B 64 0B 36 0A FB 0A CB
    (11) 127 - 0A 90 0A 5E 0A 22 09 F3 09 C5 09 8B 09 5E 09 31 09 04 08 D4 08 A5 08 76 08 44 08 17 07 E6 07 B0
    (11) 128 - 07 82 07 54 07 22 06 F4 06 B9 06 89 06 4E 06 1C 05 E0 05 B1 05 83 05 49 05 1C 04 EF 04 C2 04 92
    (1) Stat of fd(6) : st_mode(100660) st_uid(10353) st_gid(10353) st_ino(45439) st_size(54780053)
E/SQLiteLog: (1) File name of fd(6) : /data/data/par.fg.fg2022/databases/bdGeneral
    (1) Stat of /data/user/0/par.fg.fg2022/databases/bdGeneral : st_mode (100660) st_uid (10353) st_gid (10353) st_ino(45439) st_size(54780053)
    (11) database disk image is malformed in "PRAGMA journal_mode"
D/SQLiteConnection: Corruption detected - isPrimary: true, address: @e72e58b
E/SQLiteDatabase: Database corruption detected in open()
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabaseCorruptException: database disk image is malformed (code 11 SQLITE_CORRUPT[11]): , while compiling: PRAGMA journal_mode
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:1521)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForString(SQLiteConnection.java:1108)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.setJournalMode(SQLiteConnection.java:655)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.setJournalFromConfiguration(SQLiteConnection.java:550)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:406)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:226)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:743)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:288)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:255)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner(SQLiteDatabase.java:1581)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:1522)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:1163)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:470)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:413)
        at par.fg.fg2022.Activities.Actualizar.lambda$onCreate$3$Actualizar(Actualizar.java:100)
        at par.fg.fg2022.Activities.-$$Lambda$Actualizar$jerTyJVebVH9dcw480hY08ibPgE.run(Unknown Source:2)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
E/DefaultDatabaseErrorHandler: Corruption reported by sqlite on database: /data/user/0/par.fg.fg2022/databases/bdGeneral
E/SQLiteDatabase: DB wipe detected: package=par.fg.fg2022 reason=corruption file=/data/user/0/par.fg.fg2022/databases/bdGeneral ctime=2023-07-04T21:59:02Z mtime=2023-07-04T21:59:02Z atime=2023-07-04T21:58:52Z checkfile [unable to obtain timestamp]
    java.lang.Throwable: STACKTRACE
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.wipeDetected(SQLiteDatabase.java:3994)
        at android.database.DefaultDatabaseErrorHandler.onCorruption(DefaultDatabaseErrorHandler.java:68)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.onCorruption(SQLiteDatabase.java:3130)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:1526)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:1163)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:470)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:413)
        at par.fg.fg2022.Activities.Actualizar.lambda$onCreate$3$Actualizar(Actualizar.java:100)
        at par.fg.fg2022.Activities.-$$Lambda$Actualizar$jerTyJVebVH9dcw480hY08ibPgE.run(Unknown Source:2)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
```

The weirdest thing is that it was working for years but suddenly I got this problem.  Any idea?

Comment: Do not use OutputStream. Use FileOutputStream.

Comment: Thank you for your help but infortunately problem continues....